# Given f(x) a polynomial in DocPolynom format, how to find f(x-1) as a polynomial? (MatLab)

Tags: matlab

I'm using DocPolynom a lot at the moment (see here if unfamiliar: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/f3-28024.html)

I have a polynomial `f = DocPolynom(v)` where `v` is a vector of coefficients. I really would like to be able to convert `f` to the polynomial corresponding to f(x-a), where `a` is a pre-determined constant. Does anyone know if/how I can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what this object you are writing is supposed to do, but you might play with my sympoly toolbox, which allows symbolic computation on polynomials. It is on the file exchange.

If all you have are simple polynomials, you can always use conv to compute powers of (x - a), adding them together. Thus, if we have the polynomial

```
P(x) = 3*x^2 + 2*x + 1
```

and we wish to form the polynomial Q(x) = P(x-3), it takes only a few operations.

```
Q = 3*conv([1 -3],[1 -3]) + 2*conv([0 1],[1 -3]) + 1*conv([0 1],[0 1])
Q =
     3   -16    22
```

Answer (score 1):

Although not a direct answer, since you know the coefficients of the polynomial, you can evaluate the polynomial by `polyval` at the inputs `x-a` and using the resultant output you can use `polyfit` to get the coefficients of the polynomial that passes through your data.

```
v=[1 2 3];
x=1:3;
a=2;
y=polyval(v,x-a);
polyfit(x,y,2) % 2 here is the order of your polynomial (i.e. length(v)-1)
ans =

    1.0000   -2.0000    3.0000
```

To do this, you need at least N+1 data points, where N is the order of your polynomial.